# App Store Connect API / Hot Restart Setup from VS 2022 in Windows

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, maui, hot-reload

I am trying to enable IOS development in VS 2022 for windows. I understand it requires an apple dev account. I have this info on my MAC machine and everything works as expected. However, in Windows, it needs to setup Hot Restart / Reload. During the process, it asks about the app store connect API key. I am providing the correct details (precisely as I did with MAC), It complains and throws an error message.

[image: error message].

Answer (score 0):

If you use a personal account, you need to generate an API key. About how to generate an API Key, you can follow the steps blew: Go to App Store Connect, click User and Access, go to Keys tab, choose [App Store Connect API](https://idmsa.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/signin?appIdKey=891bd3417a7776362562d2197f89480a8547b108fd934911bcbea0110d07f757&path=%2Faccount%2F&rv=1#!/membership/R27MT28R2X) , then generate an API Key. After that, you can open VS and go to **Tools**-> **Options**-> **Xamarin**-> **Apple Accounts** -> **Add**-> **Individual account**, enter your API key.
(Note: Please be careful to save the downloaded key, it can only be downloaded once.)

For more details, you can see [Creating API Keys for App Store Connect API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/creating_api_keys_for_app_store_connect_api) on developer.apple.com.

If you have already filled in Api Key. You can check whether the issuer ID and Key ID are entered correctly, and check whether the API has been revoked on developer.apple.com. Furthermore, you could also try to generate a new API Key and check if this issue still exists.

**Update:**

Deleted apple account from VS

Removed certificates from AppData\Local\Xamarin\iOS\Provisioning\Certificates

Removed profiles from AppData\Local\Xamarin\iOS\Provisioning\Profiles

Added Apple account

Set to Automatic Provisioning and select team, it will error again but will reinstall the certificates

Manually download provisioning profile and copy it to AppData\Local\Xamarin\iOS\Provisioning\Profiles

Run the archiving process should error out again but the “id” or name of the provisioning will be displayed in the error

Rename the provisioning file to match and rerun archiving.

Comment: thanks, I have created many keys with different permission (developer, manager, ...), However, every account works in MAC and none worked in windows.

Comment: According to what you said, every account works in MAC, which proves that there is no problem with the account. You can try the method I updated in the answer.

Comment: The problem is in step 3 (Added Apple account) you cannot add an individual accounts because of the error posted.

Comment: Were you able to add Apple account normally before? Can you add a screenshot of this error to your question?